# REGEX to Capture only address blocks and exclude text separated by blank lines

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a large document of address blocks that contain a myriad of different address formats.

The document has sections of paragraphs, pictures, and random text and throughout these different sections are large groups of address blocks.  The address blocks will always have a blank line before and after the address and they will always end with a ZIP (+4 is optional).

Unfortunately, the Addresses vary so much that I can't come up with a way to capture the specific components (sometimes there is only recipient and others there is recipient and ATTN line.  sometimes there is a secondary unit address, etc..).

I did come up with a regex pattern to match the address blocks within the document; however, it is not completely accurate.  I would like to capture only the address blocks but my pattern is also capturing random lines of text in between the address blocks.

My pattern is:

```
[regex]$pattern = "(?xm)\n(
^[\w\d\-\.\s]+(\d{5})(?:\-\d{4})?
)";
```

An example of what it is capturing is:

```
       DUSHANBE PLACEISTAN

       DASHB FARMINTON
       PSC 123 BOX 1
       APO AP 12345




       DETACHMENT ATTACHMENT
       SECURITY GUARD OFFICE
       AMERICAN EMB E01
       UNIT 1712
       APO AE 54321-7798

       TASHKENT UZBEKISTAN

       TONE TENTKASH DOS
       75485 TORSHEN PL
       WASHINGTON DC 12345-1234
```

In the example above it should not be capturing DUSHANBE PLACEISTAN or TASHKENT UZBEKISTAN (only the blocks of addresses).

Any and insight into how to properly parse the text would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to tell us what characteristic(s) of a block of text make it an address. For example, is it an address block if and only if the last line ends with a 5- or 9- digit zip code?

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Yes, that is the case.  It always ends with a zip code (+4 is optional) and I have provied samples of various addresses in the question above for reference.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to include that information. We can then delete our comments.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use the regular expression

```
(?:^\w+(?: +\w+)* *\r?\n)+\w+(?: +\w+)* +\d{5}(?:\-\d{4})? *$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kYgRtg/3/)

The regex engine performs the following operations (I've escaped the space character to make them more visible).

```
(?:           # begin non-cap grp
  ^           # match beginning of line
  \w+         # match 1+ word chars
  (?:\ +\w+)  # match 1+ spaces, 1+ word chars in non-cap grp
  *           # execute non-cap grp 0+ times
  \ *\r?\n    # match 0+ spaces, return char(s) 
)             # end non-cap grp             
+             # execute non-cap grp 1+ times
\w+           # match 1+ word chars
(?:\ +\w+)    # match 1+ spaces, 1+ word chars in non-cap grp
*             # execute non-cap grp 0+ times
\ +           # match 1+ spaces
\d{5}         # match 5 digits
(?:\-\d{4})   # match '-' then 4 digits in non-cap grp
?             # optionally match non-cap grp
\ *           # match 0+ spaces
$             # match end of line
```

Answer (score 0):

If there has to be a newline in front of the first line, you might also use an lookbehind assertion for a new line and match as few lines as possible until you can match the zip code format.

```
(?<=\r?\n)(?:\S.*\r?\n)+?.*\d{5}(?:\-\d{4})?$
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=\r?\n)` Positive lookbehind, assert what is on the left is a newline
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\S.*\r?\n` Match the whole line, starting with a non whitespace char preventing empty lines
- `)+?` Close group and repeat 1+ times non greedy
- `.*\d{5}(?:\-\d{4})?` Match the whole line ending on the zip code pattern
- `$` End of line

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5cr%3f%5cn%29%28%3f%3a%5cS.*%5cr%3f%5cn%29%2b%3f.*%5cd%7b5%7d%28%3f%3a%5c-%5cd%7b4%7d%29%3f%5cr%3f%24&i=%0d%0aDASHB+FARMINTON%0d%0aPSC+123+BOX+1%0d%0aAPO+AP+12345%0d%0a%0d%0aDUSHANBE+PLACEISTAN%0d%0a%0d%0aDETACHMENT+ATTACHMENT%0d%0aSECURITY+GUARD+OFFICE%0d%0aAMERICAN+EMB+E01%0d%0aUNIT+1712%0d%0aAPO+AE+54321-7798%0d%0a%0d%0aTASHKENT+UZBEKISTAN%0d%0a%0d%0aTONE+TENTKASH+DOS%0d%0a75485+TORSHEN+PL%0d%0aWASHINGTON+DC+12345-1234%0d%0a&o=m)

An alternative pattern could be matching all lines that don't end with the zip code pattern until you encounter the lines that does.

```
(?<=\r?\n)(?:(?!.*\d{5}(?:\-\d{4})?$)\S.*\r?\n)+.*\d{5}(?:\-\d{4})?$
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5cn%29%28%3f%3a%28%3f!.*%5cd%7b5%7d%28%3f%3a%5c-%5cd%7b4%7d%29%3f%24%29%5cS.*%5cr%3f%5cn%29%2b.*%5cd%7b5%7d%28%3f%3a%5c-%5cd%7b4%7d%29%3f%5cr%3f%24&i=%0d%0aDASHB+FARMINTON%0d%0aPSC+123+BOX+1%0d%0aAPO+AP+12345%0d%0a%0d%0aDUSHANBE+PLACEISTAN%0d%0a%0d%0aDETACHMENT+ATTACHMENT%0d%0aSECURITY+GUARD+OFFICE%0d%0aAMERICAN+EMB+E01%0d%0aUNIT+1712%0d%0aAPO+AE+54321-7798%0d%0a%0d%0aTASHKENT+UZBEKISTAN%0d%0a%0d%0aTONE+TENTKASH+DOS%0d%0a75485+TORSHEN+PL%0d%0aWASHINGTON+DC+12345-1234%0d%0a&o=m)